# Unable to contribute information

Tags: discussion

I saw a question I'd like to answer, and contribute information to in order to help people who might also be looking for the same thing. Problem is, it says I have to have reputation. I just want to post to help with this one problem, I have nothing else really to say or any questions to ask in order to gain reputation, so is it possible to hand the answer to someone else here and have them go add it to the thread?

the thread I'd like to help on is [HP DV7 Beats Audio alsa.base Modification. What should be the line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70156/hp-dv7-beats-audio-alsa-base-modification-what-should-be-the-line?newreg=60057b12b64b4eabb3afe69ea076dd5f) I'd like to say that I added options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv7-4000 to alsa-base.conf and it worked for my HP DV7, the previous suggestion to add model=ref resulted in a muffled sound and no subwoofer but adding options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv7-4000 sounds great!

Thanks :)

Comment: AskUbuntu does require that people have been around 'for a bit' to discourage casual, and bad answers.  Please check [https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) - I know it can be frustrating when you want to add comments to help people further on!

Comment: I have unprotected the question temporarily to allow you to add your answer.

Comment: @zanna thank you so much. I was able to add an answer. I hope others might find the information useful. I know it's been a long time but I have been extremely busy.